# How to create a new button in WordPress admin menu

Tags: wordpress

Please tell me how to create a new button here (at the bottom of the dashboard left-hand navigation): http://prntscr.com/6rlbda

This button only needs to transmit one GET parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use add_menu_page() function. Refer: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: Try and keep all information in this post whereever possible, and rather than a link to a site that might not be valid in the future, post as much information here, including what you tried, and where the problem arose,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add a "button" to the menubar, only a standard link (though you can choose the icon.)

Also your question doesn't specify what you actually want the button (or page it links to) to *do*, but the standard approach is:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_menu_item' );

function register_my_menu_item() {
    # the add_action ensures this is only run when admin pages are displayed
    add_menu_page( 'Example page', 'Example menu', 'manage_options', 'query-string-parameter', 'my_menu_item');
}

function my_menu_item() {
    # your new admin page contents (or behaviour go here)
    echo 'Hello World!';
}
```

(This should ideally go in a plugin, but it can also go in your theme's `functions.php`)

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add function in the functions.php in your theme, or in a plugin.

The new button will be showed only when the plugin or the theme where you added the code is active.

Please refer to this[codex pace](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page).

This is the only proper way to do it, as far as I am aware.